# The list-buffers command. How to make the 'Buffer' column sort case-insensitively, when click on it?

Tags: sorting, buffer-list

`C-x C-b` is normally bound to the `list-buffers` command.
The resulting buffer has various columns, which are CRM, Buffer, Size, Mode, and File.

When I can click on the `Buffer` column-header, it will toggle sorting the contents of the window, switching between ascending and descending sorting according to the buffer name. Which is fine. However, the sorting according to the buffer name is case-sensitive.

What I would prefer is for the contents of the window to sort with the buffer name being considered *case-insensitively*. As it is now, for ascending order, names that begin with (A-Z) are shown first, then names (a-z) are shown after them. I would prefer if the *case of the letters was ignored*, when sorting by buffer name.

Answer (score 1):

`list-buffers` uses tabulated list sorting, which I've not delved into.  `ibuffer` OTOH has a specific command for sorting by name, and you could redefine it to be case-insensitive like so:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'ibuf-ext
  ;; Create a case-insensitive ibuffer sort command.  Derived from
  ;; `ibuffer-do-sort-by-alphabetic' which is defined in ibuf-ext.el
  ;; by (define-ibuffer-sorter alphabetic ...).
  (define-ibuffer-sorter alphabetic-ignore-case
    "Sort the buffers by their names, ignoring case."
    (:description "buffer name")
    (string-collate-lessp
     (buffer-name (car a))
     (buffer-name (car b))
     nil t))
  ;; Assign the new command to the 'Name' header keymap.
  (define-key ibuffer-name-header-map [(mouse-1)]
    'ibuffer-do-sort-by-alphabetic-ignore-case)
  (put 'ibuffer-make-column-name 'header-mouse-map
       ibuffer-name-header-map))
```

`ibuffer` is a super-charged replacement for `list-buffers` so I recommend binding `C-x C-b` to this (and then doing some reading about its excellent features -- use `?` in the buffer or `C-h f ibuffer-mode` to read its primary help).

Comment: I delved a little bit into `tabulated-list` and could not find an easy way to implement what the OP requested. The best that I could do was to redefine `tabulated-list--get-sorter` to use `string-collate-lessp` instead of `string<` (which is hard-wired, hence the need to rewrite the function)t. +1 for `ibuffer`.

Comment: Thank you phils for a rapid response, and that solution! Two things though ... 

1. I put it into my .emacs  file and evaluated the .emacs  buffer so that it is in effect. But then when going into `list-buffer` and testing it, it didn't work. I am running latest emacs on Windows 10.  [GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2020-11-19]  

2. I have seen the `ibuffer` before, and it has the same issue, except the column is called "Name" in `ibuffer`.  The good news is that your solution DOES work in the `ibuffer` for the "Name" column!

Comment: @phils -- My comment above ... I should have read your suggested answer a little more closely. Your solution IS for the `ibuffer`.  And I have confirmed it works, as mentioned in my comment above. Thanks! +1  @NickD -- If I insist on using `list-buffers` rather than `ibuffer` (probably I will switch to using `ibuffer` always, as suggested), then I can try your fix to the hard-wired function, as you indicated, for the `list-buffers`.  So thanks all around!

Comment: Yes, this answer doesn't affect `list-buffers` at all.  If you like `ibuffer` though you can `(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-b") 'ibuffer)` and then just forget about the default `list-buffers`.